# What should be the result of !$a - $a

Tags: php, math

I have this code:

```
$a = 1;
$a = !$a - $a;
echo $a;
```

I was thinking of `!0` - kidding, but the output is `-1`. Unfortunately I can't understand why the result is `-1`. It would be great if somebody explains.

Comment: !$a casts to boolean TRUE and reverses logic, giving FALSE; FALSE - $a casts FALSE to an integer for the subtraction giving 0 - 1, giving -1.... it's pretty straightforward

Comment: Mahdi's answer is the right one.

Comment: Because you're using a logical operator on a numeric operand. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 9):

If you do `var_dump(!$a);` you'll see that `!$a` is not an integer anymore. It's a `boolean false` and it's not because of its original value which is `1` in your case. Take a look at this:

```
$a = 5;
$a = !$a - $a; 
echo $a;    // output: -5
```

You might be also intersted to do the following as well:

```
$a = 5;
$a = false - $a;
echo $a;     // output: -5
```

So, as you can see, `!$a` means `false` and it translats to `0`. So, based on your example, we have something like this:

```
$a = 1;
$a = !$a - $a;
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
$a = 0 - 1;
```

Which is `-1`.

Further more, `true` also translates to `1`. You wanna be sure? give it a try:

```
$a = 5;
$a = true - $a;
echo $a;    // output: -4
```

I guess that should be clear enough now! Let me know if it's still confusing.

Comment: Came here to say the exact same thing.

Comment: It took you 1 min and 25 seconds to write this?

Comment: @MihaiIorga LOL I know right! Mahdi Nice answer for such a simple question :)

Answer (score 3):

It's because the unary NOT is evaluated *before* the subtraction, i.e. it evaluates like this:

```
$a = (!$a) - $a;
```

*Here, `!$a` => `false` is cast to `0` as well because of the subtraction.*

To get what you were expecting, you should put parentheses:

```
$a = !($a - $a);
```

See also: [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: You clearly answered this too quickly to be legitimate. I'm watching you, Uruhara!

Comment: @rdlowrey Eek! It's the stopwatch police!

Answer (score 1):

Well `$a` is 1

Thus `NOT $a` which is `!$a` is false (which is converted to 0)

```
0 - 1 = -1
```

The operator `!` is the logical not operator